# Send JSON data with NSURLConnection in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json

I am trying to send JSON data to a web server via the code below. For some reason, the request does not seem to be going out. What does it look like I am missing? Also the result from NSURLConnection (retStr) is always empty?

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test sending ios" forKey:@"value1"];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webserveraddress"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:60];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSString *retStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: just an opinion you should send POST variable to your server and retrieve json from it. It will be easier especially if you connect through an http connection. easier and faster. And you can simply put in the HTTPBody NSString stringWithFormat:@"var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@..." and on the server you have in php $_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2'] etc...

Comment: @NicolasManzini Can you give me some example code for this. I tried rearranging the code above and removing NSJSONSerialization, and I am still not getting any POST on my web server? Would I need to remove the: [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send simple data in post vars to your webserver running php you simply do this in

**Example**

```
NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@",@"var1String" ,@"var2string" ,[NSnumber numberWithBool:YES]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webserver.com/yourScriptPHP.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
// this is for you to be able to get your server answer. 
// you will need to make your class a delegate of NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate
myClassPointerData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

**Implement**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [myClassPointerData appendData:data]
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection DidFinishLoading {
    // do what you want with myClassPointerData the data that your server did send you back here
    // for info on your server php script you just need to do: echo json_encode(array('var1'=> $var1, 'var2'=>$var2...));
    // to get your server sending an answer
}
```

Comment: dont forget to release your NSURLCOnnecion and your myClassPointerData

Answer (score 0):

once check like this

ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ur url"]];

```
[request setPostValue:appdelegate.userid forKey:@"userid"];
[request setPostValue:self.nameLbl.text forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:self.website.text forKey:@"website"];

NSLog(@"~~~~~~ request~~~~~ %@",request);

[request setTimeOutSeconds:5000];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending as JSON, you could simply send it the normal way - by setting the request's HTTPBody with POST method.

Only differenc you need to make if you need to make a call such as 
'http://abc.example.com/user_profile.json?user[first_name]=fdffdf&user[last_name]=dffdf'

is, you need to have your dictionary keys have a prefix.
That is, 'first_name=fdffdf' needs to be changed to 'user[first_name]=fdffdf'.

Try this bit of code to change your parameter dictionary to the required format for JSON..

```
for (id key in [self allKeys]) {
NSString *newKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]", parent, key];
[result setObject:[self objectForKey:key] forKey:newKey];
}
```